# How to generate namedQuery by hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, named-query

I am working in a project where Java entity classes are generated from db scheme by hibernate tool. I would like to have named queries in the generated classes to be able to find entities by one of their non primary-key field. I would like to have namedQueries like this: findUserByName or findUserByHeight. Named queries would be an optimal choice for this purpose besides entitymanger.find() and Criteria API.

My question is how to configure hibernate tool / hbm2java / reverse engineering strategy to generate namedQueries for each column in a db table. I did not find any corresponding information on the internet. I hope this is possible. Using Eclipse JPA 2.0 Persistance manager in NetBeans I was able to generate named queries.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Spring, then you should have a look at [Hades](http://redmine.synyx.org/projects/show/hades). It provides the functionality to create SQL Statements out of Method names.
The only thing you need to do is to write a Interface (DAO) - the implmentation of it is "simulated" by Hades.

So you can do something like writing a method declaration like:

```
public interface CustomerDAO {
  List<Customer> findByFirstName(String firstName);
}
```

If the method name -- sql statment mapping does not work for complex queries then Hades provieds the functionalty to use statements defined in annotations.

```
@Query("FROM Deal as x WHERE customer = :customer AND (x.zombie = 'NONE' OR x.zombie ='NEW')")
Deal findActiveDealByCustomer(@Param("customer") Customer customer);
```

@see http://redmine.synyx.org/projects/show/hades  - i really like that project

Answer (score 0):

This is not really Java's style, I'm afraid.

The methods you would like remind me of `Rails` and `Grails`, concepts that don't work well with a static beast like Java (don't get me wrong, I love my beast).

[Spring Roo](http://static.springsource.org/spring-roo) mimics what rails and grails do and generates Controller methods like the ones you would like but that would mean you would have to use Spring Roo.

Another Idea would be to post-process your generated code by using a [source code parser](http://code.google.com/p/javaparser/). But that's also going to be a tough call.

Probably your best bet is to get the code of the hbm2java tool and add a hook for your routines.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be better to manually generate only those queries you really need? I have the same setup with my pojos and mappings being autogenerated and also the wish to use named queries.

I solved it, in creating a new centralised mapping file, which holds ALL my named queries. Even if I have to do my autogenerating REVENG process again, this query mappingfile isn't replaced and still works.

I understand what you are wanting to do. You want to make REVENG incorporating the named queries automatically into the generated code / mappings. I came to the same point when starting with REVENG. But then I realised, that REVENG should not be responsible for this. It should rather generate stuff out of a db-schema. Not more and not less. Named-Queries are not part of the db-schema. So REVENG shouldn't be misused here.

Have a look [here](http://miquelmillan.com/2012/04/09/hibernate-named-queries-and-non-mapped-objects-sweetness/):